# Can I ask a EEA family permit in Italy for a second time, 2 months before my current one expires?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, family, uk-visa

I have a EEA family permit that expires at the end of August. As I need to return to Italy in July, and I will be there 3 weeks, I want to take advantage of that and ask for the EEA family permit again, due to is the only way to travel ( I am also going to ask the residence card but after), and I need to travel meanwhile my residence card will be processed.

I want to ask if it is possible to ask my EEA family permit during the travel in July ( in July I will have my current EEA family permit active, nor expired).

Do you think they deny the new EEA family permit because I am a holder of an active EEA Family permit?

Do you know the case of someone who has done this before? Do you know the outcome?

Do you know if they could say NO or deny my application (only because of the fact that at the moment of the application I have an EEA family permit already active)?

In the case they accept to make a new EEA family permit, is the other one canceled?

Thank you very much!